# react changing page title

Tags: react-router, react-helmet

I know I can use [react-document-title](https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title) and [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to change the page title. But I have a problem.

react-document-title can set the default page title like:

```
function App() {
  // Use "My Web App" if no child overrides this
  return (
    <DocumentTitle title='My Web App'>
      <SomeRouter />
    </DocumentTitle>
  );
}
```

Can react-helmet do the same thing?

In addition, from the example in github, both of them are using a static title. Can they do thing like youtube where the title is not static?

If you are in youtube main page, the page title show Youtube.
if you are watching a video, the page title shows the video's name with `-youtube`.

Obviously, `- youtube` is static, and the video's name is dynamic.

The goal is that I want to set the default title in router.js (like `react-document-title`), then if the component requires the  title (default title plus the component's page title), change the page title. If it's not required, then use the default title using this code:

```
function App() {
  // Use "My Web App" if no child overrides this
  return (
    <DocumentTitle title='My Web App'>
      <Router path="/" component={Home} />
    </DocumentTitle>
  );
}

function HomePage() {
  // Use "Home" while this component is mounted
  return (
    //trying to do something like this
    <DocumentTitle title='${default title } -Home'>
      // output: My Web App - Home
      <h1>Home, sweet home.</h1>
    </DocumentTitle>
  );
}
```

Can you show the example, since I need it to understand this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `document.title` for changing the title of the page as the code below.

```
import React from 'react';

const DemoComponent= () => {
  document.title = "This is demo Component";
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <h1> My Component</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DemoComponent;
```

Here I have set the title of the page "This is demo Component". So, when this component is rendered, the title of the page will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this function which i customly built .

1. get the href location of your url.
2. split the path name
3. use it as your dynamic page title

`const basename = (path) => { return path.split("/").reverse()[1] } const pageTitle = (typeof window !== 'undefined' )?basename(window.location.href): null`